# Using weka from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, weka

I want to make predictions from a Weka saved model without opening Weka Explorer or Simple CLI interfaces. So I created a batch file:

```
@ECHO ON

title Weka caller

set root=C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8\

cd /D %root%

java -classpath weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression -T Z:\ARFF_FILES\TestSet_regression.arff -l Z:\WEKA_MODELS\Regression_model_03_05_2018.model -p 0
```

I have this error message:

```
C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8>java -classpath weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression -T Z:\ARFF_FILES\TestSet_regression.arff -l Z:\WEKA_MODELS\Regression_model_03_05_2018.model -p 0
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no/uib/cipr/matrix/Matrix
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: no.uib.cipr.matrix.Matrix
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Is someone already called weka from windows cmd shell ??

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Weka in a windows shell but the way you could do it in Linux is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
export CLASSPATH=/home/stalai/Weka/weka-3-9-1/weka.jar:.
echo $CLASSPATH
# Code that loops through various classification routines and saves the results in a corresponding text file
# Defult values
CV=103      # Cross Validation: change to 10 or keep leave one out cross validation [change by (-x)]
files=dataset.csv   # Look at the required .csv files and process them 
for i in {100..10};
 do
   java weka.classifiers.meta.AttributeSelectedClassifier -t $files -x $CV >> $CorAttEvalResults -E "weka.attributeSelection.CorrelationAttributeEval " -S "weka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T -1.7976931348623157E308 -N $i" -W weka.classifiers.lazy.IBk -- -K 1 -W 0 -A "weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch -A \"weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last\""
done
```

In this example, we are eliminating the top 100 features down to 10 by using a correlation based feature ranker and saving the results in CorAttEvalResults following a leave-one-out-cross validation. The CV=103 is infact the total number of classes in the dataset.csv file.

Once you figured out the desired model, change the corresponding flag values and reload the model. Let me know if you need more help!

Also I would recommend using CSV instead of Arff as it is easier to handle cross platform if you wanna expand your code or something like that.